# Why is Tomcat not running a simple web app from IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

This has been asked before but the only answers I saw were "restart or re-install tomcat" and similar and they're not working.

I'm trying to get a simple Java web app to work. I downloaded the example from a textbook website. The web app compiles with 0 errors but I get the following message:

```
 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 SEVERE: Cannot start server, server instance is not configured
```

**This is a picture view of the error**

[image]

**Here is images of the run configuration**

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps you guys see what could possibly be going wrong. I tried to install Apache tomcat 9 and 8 and I have both and I switch between them to see if any work but I get the same error each time. I know it has nothing to do with conflicting versions because the error was happening even when I only had Tomcat 9.

Comment: As a note, the kind of application you're writing is obsolete; modern tools handle all of that headache for you (e.g., [this is an entire Spring Boot application](https://twitter.com/rob_winch/status/364871658483351552)). Spring Boot, Micronaut, Dropwizard are all popular.

Comment: (A) What version and edition (Community, Ultimate) of IntelliJ are you using? And what is your host OS? And what Maven archetype did you use to create your project? (B) Ignore the comment about using the other various technologies. There is nothing wrong with writing your own Servlet. At the least, doing so is educational. And for many apps, doing so is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: CATALINA_BASE points to a different tomcat installation. An environment variable somewhere?

Comment: Make a clean Tomcat installation, then follow this: https://mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-run-debug-web-application-on-tomcat/ .